# Apache2 stops after system graceful-restart

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, imagemagick

System's effected: Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 18.04, not 14.04.

Frequency: Approx. around 24 - 36 hours.

```
[Wed May 08 03:44:25.964597 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7670] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Wed May 08 03:44:26.173977 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7670] AH00163: Apache/2.4.39 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1b configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 08 03:44:26.173993 2019] [core:notice] [pid 7670] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed May 08 03:49:04.001821 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7670] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Wed May 08 03:49:04.210024 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7670] AH00163: Apache/2.4.39 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1b configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 08 03:49:04.210039 2019] [core:notice] [pid 7670] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed May 08 03:54:39.080243 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7670] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Wed May 08 03:54:39.298743 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7670] AH00163: Apache/2.4.39 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1b configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 08 03:54:39.298757 2019] [core:notice] [pid 7670] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed May 08 03:59:17.197985 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7670] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Wed May 08 03:59:17.447167 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7670] AH00163: Apache/2.4.39 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1b configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 08 03:59:17.447182 2019] [core:notice] [pid 7670] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed May 08 04:03:55.095152 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7670] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart

libgomp: could not create thread pool destructor.
```

Manual restart of the apache service is needed after it has stopped.
Don't know why it involves `libgomp`...

2017-07-30:
Seems like it has something todo with the combination Apache - PHP - ImageMagick

Removing ImageMagick from Apache-PHP but keeping it in PHP-CLI removed the problem.
But it's not fix...

Comment: Hello, I just want to confirm that have the same problem on my Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're restarting Apache every 5 minutes? How many applications are being served? How many active connections?

Enable the server status page. It will allow you to see how many processes and connections are opened at any time. Very useful for debugging.

Do not reload Apache every 5 minutes. Apache is not stable with many reloads when it has to serve many services or many connections. It's running into resources limits like shared memory, semaphores and other.

If you're trying to do something to dynamically register and configure (many) applications so often. Gotta ditch Apache and use either haproxy or nginx instead.

Looks like you're potentially running PHP applications? With mod_php?

Gotta be a bug in a C library, called by PHP code, called by mod_php, called within Apache.

Ditch mod_php, it's rubbish that make Apache unstable, mod_python and mod_perl have long been deprecated for the same reason. If you run PHP applications, run with fastcgi instead.

Answer (score 0):

From this [article](https://alijosie.medium.com/this-is-why-our-3000-apache-servers-went-down-on-the-first-day-of-2022-3cc5e9639587), it looks like the problem has to do with the version of Imagick. Update to a newer version and the problem will go away.